# Display index.html after completing other actions

Tags: node.js

I have a some app which gets weather information and after that displayed it to page.
Below is a piece of my code.

```
app.post ('/weather',function(req,res){
  let city = req.body.city;
  $('#text').text(city);
  fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html', $.html());
  getWeatherData(city);
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

I understood that Node.js has an event-driven architecture capable of asynchronous I/O, but how can I do that this action `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');` was done latest? Beacuse now I got weather information, write it in index.html, but display the old version of index.html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can put the `res.sendFile` inside the callback of `fs.writeFile` Like so:

```
fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/index.html', html, () => {
  getWeatherData(city)
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Also it seems like you are writing a different file per user. Just a suggestion, but I would recommend looking into [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) to do this with more efficiency.

Comment: @Victoria is it throwing an error, if so what is it throwing. If not, be more specific about exactly what is happening

Comment: @Victoria if it is not working what is happening. Is an error throwing?

Comment: tnx, I fixed this task